# Using multiple database connections on the same model with thread safety in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra, octopus

I have a Sinatra application that is written in jruby and compiled into java and deployed on multi threaded Apache Tomcat server.

In one of the controllers, I want to be able to specify the model to use a particular database connection. So far I have looked at [octopus gem](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus). I am not sure if octopus is thread safe or not.

Is there an easy way to do this while being thread safe?

Comment: Which threads are you talking about?

Comment: @maxple The threads that serve a request on the server.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211547/how-to-make-activerecord-threadsafe